# Difference between 2 dates which are objects in dataframe

Tags: pandas, date

Dataframe has 2 dates which are of "object" datatype. StartDate and EndDate are in the mm/dd/yyyy format.

```
  Name        StartDate          EndDate
  bou1        1/9/2017           1/10/2017
  bou2        12/31/2016         1/10/2017
```

Output:

```
  Name        StartDate          EndDate         Diff
  bou1        1/9/2017           1/10/2017       1
  bou2        12/31/2016         1/10/2017       10
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated !!

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.EndDate)-pd.to_datetime(df.StartDate)
`

Comment: @Wen: Thank you, but  I get the invalid syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first need to convert to datetime for those columns and then subtract.

try

```
df['startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])
df['difInDate'] = (abs(df['startDate'].sub(df['EndDate'], axis = 0))) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
print(df['difInDate'])
```

`abs` is just to make it days positive because, you are subtracting from small date to big date
alternatively you can use `(df['EndDate'].sub(df['StartDate']` too

Answer (score 0):

```
# Recreating your dataframe with dates stored as strings
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name'     : ['bou1', 'bou2'],               
                   'StartDate': ['01/09/2017','12/31/2016'],    
                   'EndDate'  : ['01/10/2017', '01/10/2017']}) 

# Date strings converted with pd.Datetime
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])               
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])

# .dt handles your calculation and .days outputs in days
df['Diff'] = (df['EndDate'] - df['StartDate']).dt.days          

# Just prints the columns in your order
df[['Name', 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'Diff']]
```